# WordPress does not load page.php, return 404.php

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, redirect, 404-error

**UPDATED!**

I am developing a theme for WordPress by following some tutorials. The main page works well, loading post of a custom post type, and the page to see the contents of the cpt also following the Wordpress nomenclature: single-{name-cpt}.php.

The problem is when I create a normal page. When entering the URL of the page, the error page appears 404.php.

I have refreshed the link structure and verified that the .htaccess is correct.

What could be happening so that it does not load page.php?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Custom links structure: /blog/%postname%/

**UPDATED!**

Function code to create cpt:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'videos_porno',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Videos porno' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Video porno' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false, //true
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => '', 'with_front' => false),
      'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_metaboxes_video_porno',
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
    )
  );


  $args= array(
    'label' => 'Servidores',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => false,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'servidores', 'videos_porno', $args );
}

function my_rewrite_flush() {
    create_post_type();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_rewrite_flush' );
```

Before implementing the code that the cpt adds, everything works correctly.

With the link structure /blog/%postname%, 
Is it possible that cpt posts and pages share the directory "/" for urls?

Answer (score 1):

To determine if there is something wrong with your server settings or with your theme, you can write a very simple theme that will display different results for the custom post type.

I just tried that with the following theme:

style.css

```
/**
 * Theme Name: WPSE
 */
```

functions.php

```
<?php
function wpse_init() {
  register_post_type( 'wpse', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'wpse',
    ),
    'public' => true,
  ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_init' );
```

index.php

```
<?php
echo 'index';
```

single-wpse.php

```
<?php
echo 'single-wpse';
```

I then created a new wpse custom post type with a slug of 'test'. When I navigated in a browser to `/wpse/test` I saw a page that said 'single-wpse' as expected.

Note: After switching themes, I needed to refresh the rewrite rules or I saw a 404 on the custom post types.

If you do this and still see a 404, then it's a server configuration issue. If you see 'single-wpse' then it's something wrong with your theme. I would guess that you are probably using the custom post type label instead of the custom post type slug.

Comment: Testing the test topic you have written, the test slug works correctly under the url / blog / wpse / test / even without restarting the permanent links. I created a normal page and it shows the text "index.php"